# when i enter the django admin using python manage.py runserver, occur 'ValueError at /admin'

Tags: python, django, admin

when operate runserver, and then enter ther url 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin', occur this error.

At the terminal, occur this error

> ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'favicon.ico'.

At the browser, occur thie error

> ValueError at /admin
> Field 'id' expected a number but got 'admin'.
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
> Django Version: 3.2.4
> Exception Type: ValueError
> Exception Value:
> Field 'id' expected a number but got 'admin'. code here

How can solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete all migrations files - except the init python file
2. `python manage.py makemigrations`
3. `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: in my dic, both of django project root app, and other apps(using create manage.py startapp) have migrations>0001_intitial.py and etc. All rootapp, and other app I have to delete migrations files?

Comment: Delete everything but `__init__.py`